# How to set the path of the file writer to location of the jar using it?

Tags: tinylog

So i recently switch from starting the jar file from a service rather than a script that first goes to the relevant directory. Is there a way to make sure that the path to the jar file is used instead of wherever the service started it? Inside the application i use the code below to get the correct path.

```
   try {
        Path p = Path.of(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

        workPath = p.getParent().toString();

        if( workPath.matches(".*[lib]")) { // Meaning used as a lib
            workPath = Path.of(workPath).getParent().toString();
        }
        settingsFile = Path.of(workPath, "settings.xml");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Logger.error(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your work path as system property:

```java
try {
    Path p = Path.of(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

    workPath = p.getParent().toString();
    if(workPath.matches(".*[lib]")) { // Meaning used as a lib
        workPath = Path.of(workPath).getParent().toString();
    }

    System.setProperty("tinylog.directory", workPath); // Set work path as system property
    settingsFile = Path.of(workPath, "settings.xml");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    Logger.error(e);
}
```

Use the system property in tinylog.properties:

```
writer        = file
writer.file   = #{tinylog.directory}/log.txt
writer.format = {date: HH:mm:ss.SSS} {level}: {message}
```

Comment: Thanks, i overwrote the settings with Configuration.set() but that's a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your are welcome :) Please mark the answer as correct if it solves the problem for you.